# Streamline Ruby: update based on object attribute only if object is not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
if SOMETHING
  charge = Object (this object has a method ID)
end

DiffObject.update_attributes(specific_attribute: charge.id)
```

But obviously, if the `SOMETHING` did not evaluate to `true` then I don't need to update anything, or in my case, I think it might be easier to just run an `update_attributes` with `specific_attribute:nil`

So what I have right now is this:

```
DiffObject.update_attributes(specific_attribute: ((defined? charge) == nil ? nil : charge.id)))
```

But something tells me there's a MUCH better way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

When you don't know whether `charge` is `nil`, you can use `try` to safely access the id. It will return the id if charge is present, and just return nil if the charge is nil, without an error.

```
DiffObject.update_attributes(specific_attribute: charge.try(:id))
```

The methods `update_attributes`, `update`, `save` etc will only save the record if it has actually changed, so you don't need to check that yourself. Just save it and let ActiveRecord figure out the rest.

Comment: yes but in this case, since `charge` won't have been defined, `charge.id` will throw an error, that's what I need to catch

Comment: Ah now I see. In this case you can use `try`. Will edit my answer.

Comment: see my comment on other answer below, this will throw an error if `charge` isn't defined

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveSupport`'s core extension provides a handy method `try` on almost every object.

> try(*a, &b)
>   Invokes the public method whose name goes as first argument just like public_send does, except that if the receiver does not respond to it the call returns nil rather than raising an exception.

For example, you can use `change.try(:id)`. If `change` is `nil` or something that doesn't respond to `id`, it returns `nil`, otherwise it returns the ID.

See [RailsGuide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#try) and [Rails API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) for details.

Comment: better! but i'd have to first define `charge` to be nil. is there no way to check `defined?` and `try` perhaps in one go?